# How to obtain Server Time in LinqPad

Tags: c#, linqpad

In a normal C# program you can do:

```
DateTime ServerDate = Entities.CreateQuery<DateTime>("CurrentDateTime()").AsEnumerable().First();
```

What about in the LinqPad environment? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as nice a solution but it works

```
Connection.Open();
var command = Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select GetDate()";
command.ExecuteScalar().Dump();
```

Comment: Yup if it works, it works! Thanks. Just as a side note, for MySQL, one needs to use "NOW()" instead.